# In "Weathering with You", what was Hina's real age?

Tags: weathering-with-you

If I recall correctly, when Hodaka asked about Hina's age, Hina responded that she was

> almost 18 years old.

But when Hodaka got arrested, the detective said that Hina was actually

> 15 years old, which means he's younger than Hodaka.

But [the Wiki](https://makotoshinkai.fandom.com/wiki/Hina_Amano) says that Hina was

> 18 years old.

Did the police gave incorrect information, or is the Wiki incorrect, or any explanation to the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could understand, **the wiki is not incorrect**. You are misled by the fact that you isolated this sentence out of the whole article. The wiki provides the [timeline](https://makotoshinkai.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_in_Weathering_With_You) where the events you cited (when Hodaka speaks to the detective) happened on August 2021. Hina was 15 years old at this time. During their altercation with the police, it would make sense that the police would say she's 15 *since she is at that time*. The wiki page you cited as incorrect states there that *Hina's age is 18 as of 2024, which is 3 years since 2021*.

Thus, the wiki page is just putting the latest age information from the movie timeline. *It is not incorrect, the wiki just prefers to put the latest information depending on where the story has progressed or ended.*

Both information from each websites are correct. You just need to understand that the other website you linked recounted the events on August 2021 (Hina is 15 years old at this time).

Comment: By the way, do you suggest that this topic can be should or leave it?

Comment: @kit I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: This question is just because my slightly misunderstood the timeline only. So I think that this question is kinda not very helpful I guess....

Comment: @kit For others, it might not be but for you, it cleared your misunderstanding. Questions are sometimes asked because of misunderstandings so I don't think this is not useful. It might help others who misunderstood like you did.